# Seamlessly Refresh Group Policy

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I have created an application that manipulates local Group Policy. The policies that I change require the user to log out and back in again. gpupdate.exe /force will not work because these policies are only checked upon logging in. Is there anyway that I can make this seamless? I need the system to do this with out any user intervention.

Policies Being Changed

- Disable Win + X Hotkeys
- Disable Cntrl + Alt + Delete
- Remove/Disable Desktop Icons
- Hide System Clock on taskbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explorer reads many (most) of its configuration settings from the registry only when it starts.

Once you set the settings, the logout and log back in are required to make Explorer actually USE those settings you set.

`GPupdate` only requests and updates the settings. `/force` forces settings that haven't changed to be set again anyway.   Either way, from using it you've probably noticed that even GPUpdate requires you to logout and/or reboot to apply it's changes.  If anyone could do it without the need for a logout, wouldn't you think MS would? Anyhow.... :)

Since the specific settings you listed all seem very Explorer-centric, the best you'll probably be able to do is stop and restart Explorer.exe (instead of logging the user out and back in again).

Comment: I'm not against logging out and back in. I just need a way to do it programmatically. Which sound hackie, but the process has to happen with out user intervention.

Comment: You'd need a system-level service that interfaces with [GINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) to log a user in programmatically.  Good luck on that. :(  On the other hand, restarting Explorer programmatically is easy.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested the Explorer idea and it looks like that will work just fine.